# How to add object to database from an IEnumerable collection?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ienumerable

I have a collection of ienumerable entities to be added to the database but it seems some conversion is needed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
bool InsertDetails(DataTable detailTable, string fileName)
{
    using (SunseapEBTContext context = new SunseapEBTContext())
    {
        if (InsertMaster(fileName))//if creating master record successful
        {                    
            int masterId = GetSPReadingM(m => m.FileName == fileName).SPReadingMasterId; //get MasterID of file uploaded

             var details = detailTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity()//new entity from datatable
             {
                //SPReadingId = row.Field<long>("ProductID"),

                        SPReadingMasterId = masterId,
                        BillCycleYear = int.Parse(row.Field<int>("Bill Cycle").ToString().Substring(0, 4)),
                        BillCycleMonth = byte.Parse(row.Field<byte>("Bill Cycle").ToString().Substring(4))

            });
            foreach(IEnumerable<LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity> detail  in details)
            {                       
                context.LeasingSPReadingDetailEntities.AddObject(detail);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();                    
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the foreach loop, exception is thrown

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'SunseapEBT.Domain.BillingModule.LeasingContract.Entity.LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity'

LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity class:

```
public class LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity
{
    public long SPReadingId { get; set; }
    public int SPReadingMasterId { get; set; }
    public int BillCycleYear { get; set; }
    public byte BillCycleMonth { get; set; }

}
```

More info:
A file which contains details is uploaded and will create a master record in one table. The details in the file are to be added to a separate table with the auto generated `masterId` from the first table. The issue is not being able to add the details into the database.

Edit:
I have found out why there was an error. The error was because of the contents of the file. Some rows had no values entered and the last row did not follow the format for the rest of the rows as it shows the total number of rows. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? In EF6, you could use .AddRange method: context.LeasingSPReadingDetailEntities.AddRange(details);

Comment: what is the problem you are having? from what I can tell, enumerating `details` (in `foreach`) gives `LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity` objects, instead of `IEnumerable<LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity>`

Comment: Are you getting exception any where?

Comment: @Developer I am not sure but there is no extention method for AddRange.

Comment: @RBT The exception is in the foreach loop. I have tried making it into a list then putting it in the foreach but it gives an invalid cast exception

Comment: would it be also possible to post `LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity` definition?

Comment: Change `foreach(IEnumerable<LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity> detail  in details)` to `foreach(var detail  in details)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@slawekwin comment is the answer. But I think there is a better solution, because it seems like your code is iterating 2x: 1st to generate new Enumerable (wasting memory), 2nd to add the object to context.

Might as well add the object directly when you iterate each rows.

```
foreach(var row in detailTable.AsEnumerable())
{                       
    context.LeasingSPReadingDetailEntities.AddObject(
        new LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity()//new entity from datatable
        {
           //SPReadingId = row.Field<long>("ProductID"),

           SPReadingMasterId = masterId,
           BillCycleYear = int.Parse(row.Field<string>("Bill Cycle").Substring(0, 4)),
           BillCycleMonth = byte.Parse(row.Field<string>("Bill Cycle").Substring(4)),
           AccountNumber = row.Field<string>("Account No."),
           PeriodStart = row.Field<DateTime>("Period Start"),
           PeriodEnd = row.Field<DateTime>("Period End"),
           TownCouncil = row.Field<string>("Customer Name"),
           Service = row.Field<string>("Service Type"),
           Adjustment = row.Field<string>("Adjustment"),
           Block = row.Field<string>("Blk"),
           AddressLine1 = row.Field<string>("Adress Line 1"),
           AddressLine2 = row.Field<string>("Adress Line 2"),
           AddressLine3 = row.Field<string>("Postal Code"),
           Usage = row.Field<decimal>("Usage"),
           Rate = row.Field<decimal>("Rate"),
           Amount = row.Field<decimal>("Amount")
        }
    );
}
```

--- EDIT ---

I am not sure, but I can guess that "Bill Cycle" field is neither int nor byte. Therefore, you should have retrieved it as string, then parse it to your new object. This is the part the I changed:

```
BillCycleYear = int.Parse(row.Field<string>("Bill Cycle").Substring(0, 4)),
BillCycleMonth = byte.Parse(row.Field<string>("Bill Cycle").Substring(4)),
```

Comment: Omitting the as enumerable has a compile error "System.Data.DataTable does not contain a pulbic definition for 'GetEnumerator'"  and with it still gives an invalid cast exception

Comment: Please take a look of what is `Bill Cycle` in your database. You are trying to cast it to int/ byte, but I really doubt that it is int/byte in the beginning. If it is a string, therefore: `BillCycleYear = int.Parse(row.Field<string>("Bill Cycle").Substring(0, 4)),`. Same approach need to be applied to BillCycleMonth.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to List then add the item.

```
var details = detailTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new  LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity()//new entity from datatable
         {
            SPReadingId = row.Field<long>("ProductID"),
            SPReadingMasterId = masterId,
            BillCycleYear = int.Parse(row.Field<int>("Bill Cycle").ToString().Substring(0, 4)),
            BillCycleMonth = byte.Parse(row.Field<byte>("Bill Cycle").ToString().Substring(4)),
        }).ToList();
        foreach(var detail  in details)
        {                       
            context.LeasingSPReadingDetailEntities.Add(detail);
        }
```

or better still:

```
var details = detailTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new  LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity()//new entity from datatable
         {
            SPReadingId = row.Field<long>("ProductID"),
            SPReadingMasterId = masterId,
            BillCycleYear = int.Parse(row.Field<int>("Bill Cycle").ToString().Substring(0, 4)),
            BillCycleMonth = byte.Parse(row.Field<byte>("Bill Cycle").ToString().Substring(4)),
        }).ToList();

context.LeasingSPReadingDetailEntities.AddRange(details);
```

Comment: "Does not contain a definition for AddRange" and putting into a list still gives an invalid cast exception

Answer (score 2):

You can change the problematic `foreach` loop to either of the below ones. I would prefer the first one as it is less verbose.

```
            foreach(var detail  in details)
            {                       
                context.LeasingSPReadingDetailEntities.AddObject(detail);
            }
```

OR

```
            foreach(LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity detail  in details)
            {                       
                context.LeasingSPReadingDetailEntities.AddObject(detail);
            }
```

If you look at the syntax of `foreach` loop, the very first construct `variableType` is type of the element being stored in the collection (`LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity` in your case) and NOT the type of the collection. You did the later which is why you are getting the invalid cast error.

```
foreach(variableType currentElementBeingIterated in collection){

    //code block to operate on currentElement

  }
```

Comment: I had done that previously but changed it as it still gave the invalid cast exception. I'm not sure what is wrong here :\

Comment: Your latest edit suggests that your problem is resolved now. At the end of the day you taught me something really new because you were getting the cast error at run time. My earlier assumption was that compiler should have been able to detect that type mismatch at compile time itself. Now I see that it is giving a warning instead - `Suspicious cast : there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity and System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LeasingSPReadingDetailEntity>`. I'll have to investigate this finding. Thank you for the teaching!